# Matrix multiplications: Go from ABC to BAC

Tags: matrices

I am am trying to prove that a linear transformation of a polytope $P$ is also a polytope $Q$ . My approach is to first prove that every transformation of $p \in P$ is a convex combination of all transformated vertices of $P: V_p$ to the vertices of $Q: V_Q$

So every point is of $p \in P$ is a convex combination of the vertices $V_p$ of $P$:

\begin{equation}
p = \lambda^T V_p
\end{equation}
with $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_i \geq 0$

I then multiply both matrices by $T$, which represents the linear transformation. This gives the transformation of point $p$ : $q$

\begin{equation}
q = Tp = T \lambda^T V_p
\end{equation}

If i now could get it into the following form:

\begin{equation}
q = \lambda^T A V_p
\end{equation}

Then i would have proven that any transformed point in p is a convex combination of the vertices $A V_p$, however i feel that i am close, but i don't know how i can prove this last step.

Comment: Assuming that $C$ is a vector rather than a matrix (such that your equations have the same kind of things on both sides), you can't prove that, because it's not necessarily true. It should be easy to come up with counterexamples.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Thank you. Do you see any other way to prove that this holds, for any $D$ besides $A$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: **Things that are not true cannot be proved.** It does not make sense to ask for "any other way to prove" something that is not true. It is not your _approach_ that is wrong, it is wanting to prove something that is not true in the first place.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Does that mean that there is no possible D (nonzero) for which this always holds. If that is true, my whole approach is probably wrong

Comment: You wanted to prove your conclusion for _any_ $u,v,A,B,D$. It is not true for all choices of those five variables, and therefore it has no proof! If you want _given_ $u,v,A,B$ to _find_ a $D$ that makes it work, that's a different question than the one you're asking, in which you have provided no indication that you're free to choose $D$. On the contrary you say that you _have_ $u,v,A,B,D$.

Comment: But even so, it is not true. Suppose $B=({}^0_1\,{}^0_1)$, $v=(^1_1)$ and $A=({}^0_1\,{}^1_0)$. Then nothing you do on the right of $B$ can make $BDv$ produce something with a nonzero first component.

Comment: On the other hand, if $B$ is invertible you can just choose $D=B^{-1}AB$.

Comment: @user3053216 If this is only a part of some problem, it would help if you could post the whole problem and write how you reduced it to your actual question - this would give more context and make answering your question easier.

Comment: @user8734617 i edited my post to give more context

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is where you multiplied by $T$: you would do that if you had a column of co-ordinates of a vector in some basis, but $\lambda^T V_p $ is no such thing.

Actually the answer is simple: if $L $ is the linear transformation, then $L\left(\sum_i \lambda_i V_{P,i}\right)=\sum_i \lambda_i L(V_{P,i}) $ simply because of linearity of $L $.